# Add "Nuke Comments" flag

Tags: feature-request, flags, comment-flags

For comment threads that are *way* off in the weeds, the current guidance is to flag with an "Other" flag requesting that the comment thread be nuked. This as opposed to flagging each comment individually.

My understanding is that moderators have a tool to just purge the whole thread, so this process makes it easier on them.

I have no problem with any of that, *however*, the following sequence just happened to me:

1. Comment thread went off in the weeds
2. I flagged the post to nuke the comments, as reccommended
3. The comments disappeared
4. My flag is still "Active"

Now, both parties could have just deleted their comments (unlikely). Its also possible that a moderator handled the flag and forgot to clear it. The most likely scenario I can think of would be that a moderator saw the conversation and just decided to nuke it, not even knowing about my flag. If a moderator is interested in letting us know what *actually* happened, it happened on this post: [Linq and List of Lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27790595/linq-and-list-of-lists)

The downside to this is that now a moderator will see my flag, wonder what the heck I was thinking, and probably decline it. Even if they notice that I flagged before the deletions (assuming such things are timestamped), its *still* a waste of their valuable time.

Some flags are currently auto-handled if the requested action occurs without it manually be handled. Since this obviously cannot happen for "Other" flags, I suggest adding a "Nuke Comments" flag that could be auto-handled if the posts comments are subsequently destroyed.

This saves users from posting "Other" flags in order to destroy offending threads, makes it super obvious what the flag is for, and allows for auto-handling in corner cases like this.

Comment: It's entirely possible that the mod just forgot to clear the flag after clearing the comments.  The flag will stay active until someone else clears it, which I've now done.  We don't need a new flag for this.

Comment: It will be abused or misused to no end. Adds more work to moderators for not a lot of benefits, frankly :/

Comment: @Compass Obviously the community agrees with you, but I wonder why you feel that a new flag would be abused as opposed to doing the same thing with an "Other" flag.

Comment: Because you actually have to put in a semblance of effort with the Other flag! Fill-in-the-blank!

Answer (score 4):

As you have said yourself, this is a corner case.  We don't need an entirely new type of flag just for this one corner case.  Personally I doubt the flag would be declined (if I saw a flag saying that the conversation in comments should be deleted, and a bunch of deleted comments, I'd assume someone else just deleted those comments), but even if it would get declined, this situation is just so contrived, and declined flags matter so very little, that this doesn't seem remotely worth the effort to develop.

Comment: Not concerned about the flag decline, just thinking it would save some people a headache.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET There are lots of things that could be done to revamp comment moderation.  This would be a fair bit of work, and a noticeable increase in complexity for the user, for *very* little return.  If the system is going to really get some development attention, it should be seriously overhauled; there are tons of proposals of ways to improve comment moderation/flagging.  This just isn't adding much of any value; it's one of the few cases that's supported at least *reasonably* well, even if it's not amazing.